# Meaning of "who would not let men call their wives their own to kick like Britons"

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

From *[Aurora Leigh](http://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/barrett/aurora/aurora.html#1)*:

> I had my windows broken once or twice
>   By liberal peasants, naturally incensed
>   At such a vexer of Arcadian peace,
>   **Who would not let men call their wives their own
>
>   To kick like Britons**,–and made obstacles
>   When things went smoothly as a baby drugged,
>   Toward freedom and starvation; bringing down
>   The wicked London tavern-thieves and drabs,
>   To affront the blessed hillside drabs and thieves
>   With mended morals, quotha,–fine new lives!–
>   My windows paid for't.

What is the meaning of the phrase in bold? It does not seem to be coherent at all. It's not connected to the previous words.

To whom does "to kick like Britons" refer? To "wives", to "peasants", or to the person pronouncing the sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He describes the attitude of the "liberal peasant" who claims that he owns his wife as property and therefore has the same right as every other free (male) Briton: to kick her whenever he feels like it. Romney denies both the ownership and the liberty.

Comment: Merry Xmas! That was a tough phrase. I just stared at it and tried to connect the two pieces together.

Comment: @CowperKettle Both the Brownings were given to highly elliptical expressions. They leaned heavily on the diction of the Tudor and Jacobean dramatists, but they were also pioneers in introducing the structure of contemporary casual speech into literature.

Comment: I don't think the peasants here are Britons themselves. I think *Britons* is being used as a slur. As in 'to kick like animals'. But it is a bit ambiguous today as to whether the Briton referred to is the kicker or the kickee.